# Sub Menu - Drill down menu - Expandable Listview menu

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, user-interface, drop-down-menu

Here is an image of sample program that I want to come up with.

Currently I can only create a single layer sliding menu. (left/black)

How can i create same sliding menu. **`ALL I WANT TO KNOW is the Encircled one.`** (left/white)

[image]